# Applying a global font to volusion template

Tags: css, volusion

I received a ton of help from a previous question and used:

html *
    {font-family: Helvetica !important;}

But for some reason it still doesn't change in the product descriptions. Everywhere else it is working fine. I see !important used a lot and I fear this may be the problem but the css file is massive and not designed by myself. I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to just be more specific than the template css.

If the template css uses

```
h3.title { font-family: arial !important }
```

You would need to use something like this to override it

```
.myclass h3.title { font-family: Helvetica !important }
```

You could also use inline styles to get a higher specificity than styles inside a stylesheet.